# Why function trigger valueOf when return themself?

Tags: javascript, function

Can someone explain why this clousure each time calls valueOf?

```
var v = () => {
 var c = () => c;
 c.valueOf = () => 1;
 return c;
}

v(); // 1
v()(); // 1
....
```

Comment: Because you are sending it to the console. Try `typeof v()`, you'll get "function".

Comment: The fact that closures are involved has nothing at all to do with what's happening.

Comment: @RobG It's not the answer. I can return `c.valueOf = () => 1;` and it also will call valueOf. Question is why valueOf is triggered ?

Comment: I've added an answer. I'm sure this is a duplicate but I can't find something with a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console is not standardised, it's an implementation dependent host object which tries to be helpful, see [*MDN: Console*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console).

You've run the code, but haven't told the console what to do with the result, so it makes up it's own mind what to do with it. In this case appears to call *valueOf* on the result and display that. Other implementations might do something different, including nothing at all (since the code has a result but no output).

Try it with `console.log(v())` or `alert(v())`, you'll get `() => c` because explicitly calling *console* or *alert* (typically) calls *toString* on the value passed to it, which is a reference to *v*, so it calls *v.toString* which resolves to *Function.prototype.toString*. *alert* is also implementation dependent but it's fairly simple so should comply with *de facto* behaviour.

Note that even in this case, different implementations of *console* may do different things with different objects. There are lots of questions here about why consoles give particular results, do some searches.

```js
var v = () => {
 var c = () => c;
 c.valueOf = () => 1;
 return c;
}

console.log(v()); // c = () => c;
alert(v());       // c = () => c;
alert(v()());     // c = () => c;
```